# Implementing From/Into for struct with constraints

Tags: rust, traits

Since `.max()` doesn't work for `f64`s, I'm writing a `ForceOrd` struct that asserts that the argument isn't a `NaN`. The intended usage is something like:

```
let m = xs.iter().map(|&x| ForceOrd(x)).max().unwrap().into();
```

However, I can't get the `Into` trait implementation to compile with the error:

```
conflicting implementations of trait `std::convert::Into<_>` for type `ForceOrd<_>`
```

The code ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=fdb1c292814a80ca3bb911f76247e4f4&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
#[derive(PartialEq, PartialOrd)]
pub struct ForceOrd<X: PartialEq + PartialOrd>(pub X);
impl<X: PartialEq + PartialOrd> Eq for ForceOrd<X> { }
impl<X: PartialEq + PartialOrd> Ord for ForceOrd<X> {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> std::cmp::Ordering {
        self.0.partial_cmp(&other.0).unwrap()
    }
}
/// doesn't work
impl<X: PartialEq + PartialOrd> Into<X> for ForceOrd<X> {
    fn into(x: Self) -> X { x.0 }
}
/// doesn't work either
impl<X: PartialEq + PartialOrd> From<ForceOrd<X>> for X {
    fn from(x: ForceOrd<X>) -> Self { x.0 }
}
```

Comment: Relaxing the generic constraints on this and directly implementing it on f64 should work? Is that not an option for you? I don't think its possible to add the trait bounds to an open generic across crates like you have (which should be the error you are getting if you implement _just_ `From`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have both `From` and `Into` implemented for a single type, i.e. you can't `impl From<ForceOrd<X>> for X` if you also `impl Into<X> for ForceOrd<X>`. You only need one, too. As the docs for [`Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html) and [`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) both state:

```
From<T> for U implies Into<U> for T
```

You should probably go with just a `From` implementation. You can see the following question for information on which to pick in general: [When should I implement std::convert::From vs std::convert::Into?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29812530/when-should-i-implement-stdconvertfrom-vs-stdconvertinto)

**Edit**: as implementing `From` is not (in this case) as trivial as just removing the `impl Into`, below you can see how this can be achieved for `f64`:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, PartialOrd, Debug)]
pub struct ForceOrd<X: PartialEq + PartialOrd>(pub X);

impl<X: PartialEq + PartialOrd> Eq for ForceOrd<X> { }

impl<X: PartialEq + PartialOrd> Ord for ForceOrd<X> {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> std::cmp::Ordering {
        self.0.partial_cmp(&other.0).unwrap()
    }
}

impl<X: PartialEq + PartialOrd> From<X> for ForceOrd<X> {
    fn from(x: X) -> ForceOrd<X> {
        ForceOrd(x)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let xs = vec![1.1f64, 3.5, 2.2];

    let max = xs.iter().map(|&f| <ForceOrd<f64>>::from(f)).max().unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", max); // prints "ForceOrd(3.5)"
}
```

Unfortunately I'm afraid this is as far as you can get; you won't be able to implement:

```
impl<X: PartialEq + PartialOrd> From<ForceOrd<X>> for X
```

to be able to do a final

```
<f64>::from(xs.iter().map(|&f| <ForceOrd<f64>>::from(f)).max().unwrap())
```

because `f64` is not local to this crate. You can read more about this limitation in [this very detailed blog entry by Niko Matsakis](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2015/01/14/little-orphan-impls/) and see [this question in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29789877/can-not-implement-trait-from-another-crate-for-generic-type-from-another-crate-p).

Comment: I think the OP tried each individually. The issue is attempting to implement a trait where the generic type has trait bounds that aren't declared in the current crate. I don't think this is possible. Its possible in the standard library because thats where the original traits live.

Comment: I expanded my answer with a solution to a case where there is only one `impl` in place.